# Web3Js contract deploy never resolved the promise or never exits

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to deploying Contract on Ropsten test network using infura, metamask, Web3. It get deploys but the promise never get resolved or function does not exit. I think it keep returning me the confirmation block. How would I exit the send function or resolved the promise?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider')

deploy()

function deploy() {
    const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
        'mnemonic',
        'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/ID'
    )
    const web3 = new Web3(provider)
    var contractData = fs.readFileSync('../../build/contracts/Testcontract.json');
    var contract = JSON.parse(contractData);
    var abi = contract['abi'];
    var bytecode = contract['bytecode'];

    var testContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

    var account = 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER';
    testContract.deploy({
        data: bytecode,
        arguments: ['SenderAlice', 'ReceiverBob', 120]
    })
        .send({
            from: account,
            gas: 4000000
        }, function (error, transactionHash) {

        }).once('error', function (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        }).once('transactionHash', function (transactionHash) {
            console.log('transactionHash', transactionHash);
        }).once('receipt', function (receipt) {
            console.log('receipt', receipt.contractAddress);
        }).once('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
            console.log('confirmation', confirmationNumber);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use async / await.

changes::

- put "async" before deploy function
- put "await" before testContract.deploy
- add process.exit() to return to console

---

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider')

deploy()

async function deploy() {
    const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
        'mnemonic',
        'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/id'
    )
    const web3 = new Web3(provider)
    var contractData = fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/Transfer.json');
    var contract = JSON.parse(contractData);
    var abi = contract['abi'];
    var bytecode = contract['bytecode'];

    var testContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

    var account = '0x0Fb80359dD096A1Ec1FbfDC07ddEBc2003272b0c';

    await testContract.deploy({
            data: bytecode
        })
        .send({
            from: account,
            gas: 4000000
        }, function(error, transactionHash) {

        }).once('error', function(error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        }).once('transactionHash', function(transactionHash) {
            console.log('transactionHash', transactionHash);
        }).once('receipt', function(receipt) {
            console.log('receipt', receipt.contractAddress);
        }).once('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt) {
            console.log('confirmation', confirmationNumber);
        });

    process.exit();

}
```